# On computer vs. over computer

Tags: meaning, prepositions

As far as I know, "on a tool" means that someone is using that tool and "over a tool" means that something is done using that tool as a way to do it.

For example:

> I have accepted the job ***over the phone***.
>
> Be quiet, I am ***on the phone***.

Then I just saw this sentence below:

> I do all my household accounts ***on the computer***.

Isn't it more appropriate to use "over" in this sentence above?

> I do all my household accounts ***over the computer***

Comment: The word _on_ has way too many usages and meanings to make a sweeping generalization like: _“on a tool” means someone is using that tool_. In fact, the sentence “He is on the radio” has at least four different meanings that I can think of, and only one of those four aligns with your meaning.

Comment: Over a tool, to me, would mean you did something while your body was physically above the tool, but doesn't imply even using the tool.

Answer (score 1):

These cases can be very hard to understand, as the organising ideas are not hard rules and there are many special cases.

**Over** is usually used with a medium of communications, not a general tool.

I *sent* my order

- **over email**
- **over telex**
- **over the radio**
- **over the phone**
- **over the computer**
- **over the loudspeaker**
- **over the wire**

If the thing being done is implicitly sent (an order, a tax return, a message), then you can use

I did my tax return

- **over the computer** (or *any of the other previous mediums*)

But **by** can also be used with a means

I do my accounts

- **by hand**
- **by computer**
- **by magic**
- **by email**
- **by fax**
- **by radio**
- **by phone**
- **by post** (UK)
- **by mail** (US)

An actual tool is normally **with**

I do my accounts

- **with a calculator**
- **with a computer**
- **with a pen**

You use **on** for things which can be surfaces: flat things such as desks, paper, screens, and also for transports

I do my accounts

- **on the web**
- **on the computer**
- **on a computer**
- **on a desk**
- **on a piece of paper**
- **on my phone** (I use an app on mobile phone)
- **on the phone** (I tell my accountant and they do it)
- **on the train** (I am on the train when I do it)

If there is a sense of the place being inside something else:

- **in the computer**
- **in a spreadsheet**
- **in a book**
- **in my head**

Comment: I dunno about the tax return part. I would say ON the computer there. if need be, OVER the INTERNET (as opposed to computer), because the internet is the medium.

Comment: I would interpret "I **did** my tax return..." as meaning preparation, not transmission- so **on** would be appropriate. A clearer example of a tax return as a transmission would be "I **filed** my tax return **over**...", but as @Athenosity says, "over the internet", or maybe "via the internet" might be better... or simply **online**.